# Java regex pattern matching for word ending with asterix literal

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to make a simple regex pattern work using java. I need to recognize any uppercase word ending with trailing asterisk with a sentence. From the following example :

`Test ABC*  array`

I need to identify "ABC*" or to be precise, any word with upper-casing ending with an asterisk. I tried the following pattern matching with my limited regex knowledge, but it hasn't worked out so far.

`String text = "Test ABC*  array";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\b[A-Z]+[*]?\b").matcher(text);`

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It will not work either, see my answer for a solution.

Comment: @BlackVegetable - The star is not a Kleene star--it's a simple character (the only one, in fact) in a character class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the problem is that you don't have a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) at the end after the star. So try this

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Z]+\\*\\B").matcher(text);
```

`\B` is not a word boundary, so this is exactly what you get between the `*` and a whitespace.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32oeg)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your string can contain multiple AAA* parts :

```
String text = "Test ABC*  array";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]+\\*)").matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for, simplified too.

Comment: Won't that find "ABC*" in "xyzABC*d"?

Comment: @Ted Hopp ...great catch,it will pick ABC* in your example

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple:

```
if(text.contains("*")) {
  int index = text.lastIndexOf("*");
  String ident= text.substring(0,index-1);
}
```

Comment: Note that he has a second requirement: that the string has upper-casing.  You haven't covered that, yet.

Comment: @Delta458 .. I could do that using a string comparison,but just wanted to check if I can do that using a regex pattern. Thanks though.

Comment: This won't work if the String has multiple asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the literal asterisk with a backslash.  It ends up being a double-backslash in Java.

```
"[A-Z]+\\*"
```

Comment: OP is using character class, in which he don't need to escape it. Problem is something else. See @stema's answer above.